# Determining the purity of commercial NaCl

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration, mole

I am trying to figure out how to determine the percentage of NaCl in salt. My purpose is to be able to test the purity of salt that I received before washing so that I can determine the quality of the salt and how much I should pay for it. I also want to be able to determine how good a salt washing machine works by comparing the before and after purity of the salt.

My basic understanding is that there is a standard minimum percentage of NaCl in after wash salt (usually above 99% depending on where you are), the percentage is lower for a pre-wash salt.

Is there any test to know the purity of Salt?

Thank you..